# How do I get Oracle Solaris 11.3 to lock the screen automatically

Tags: solaris, screen-lock, logout

Anybody know how I can get Oracle Solaris 11.3 to lock the screen instead of automatically logging out after a default period of time?  The time frame does not matter; it's the fact that I get logged completely out of my session that is the issue.  I can't find anything on how to change it!

Comment: Are you talking about SSH sessions or console sessions?

Comment: Console. Sorry, I'm a noob

Comment: Please, for my understanding, you _have_ console sessions logging you out and you don't want that behavior. What is the timeout for the session to get logged off?

Comment: Yes, I'm being logged out of a session after 15 minutes of inactivity.  I often get pulled away from what I'm doing and can't get back to the console in a timely fashion.  When I do get back, I have been logged out of the session and what I've been working on is gone.  I could change the timeout period to a longer period of time, but what I really need is to find out how I can get it to lock-therefore saving what I was doing; instead of logging me out and therefore losing my work.

Comment: You might familiarize yourself with the `screen` and/or `tmux` command to be able to re-attach to a session and/or lock a session.